# batch - File last modification time with seconds

Tags: batch-file, timestamp, last-modified, seconds

I want to know when a file has been modified for the last time.

I can get these infos using the following batch script:

> FOR %%i IN (myfile) DO SET modif_time=%%~ti

The problem is that I need the second of the last modification and the command `%~t` returns the date and the time with only hours and minutes.

I can only check the seconds by manually viewing the "property window" file by file.

How can I get the time with seconds in batch?

Comment: They shouldn't be sorted randomly - FAT32 has 2 second time stamp granularity but NTFS format is far finer.

Comment: I controlled again and the files are NOT sorted randomly but in the correct way even if the minute is the same. Maybe I made something wrong the first time I checked. My error. Thank you. @foxidrive

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
wmic datafile where name="FileName" get LastModified
```

`FileName` must contain the full path with double backspaces.

---

Sorting example (recent first):

```
for /f "delims=" %a in ('wmic datafile where "drive='c:' and path='\\windows\\'" get LastModified^,Name /format:table^|find ":"^|sort /r') do @echo %a
```

Comment: I get this error message: No Instance(s) Available.

Comment: About the "No Instance(s) Available" problem, see here (TLDR: just use the complete path of the file and it will work): https://superuser.com/questions/1024034/no-instances-available-error-with-the-wmic-command

Answer (score 6):

In **Windows 7 and forward** (or via Resource Kit for XP) you can use `forfiles` for this. Something like:

```
forfiles /m *.* /c "cmd /c ECHO The last modified date of: @file is: @ftime"
```

In a directory with the following files:

```
myTest.txt
myTest2.txt
```

I get:

```
The last modified date of: "myTest.txt" is: 13:21:07
The last modified date of: "myTest2.txt" is: 13:21:20
```

Comment: Well, but how can I use this to get the time as a variable in my batch file? The command opens a new cmd. Am I wrong?

Answer (score 1):

```
wmic datafile where "drive='c:' and path='\\windows\\'" get "Last Modified",Name
```

Answer (score 1):

You can embed a small JScript in the batch file to get the last modified epoch:

```
@if (@a==@b) @end /*
@echo off
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set EPOCH=0
FOR /F "delims=" %%D in ('cscript /nologo /e:jscript "%~f0" "%1"') do (
    set EPOCH=%%D
)
echo Last modified (epoch-seconds): !EPOCH!

goto :eof
*/

var fs = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
var filename = WSH.Arguments(0)
var millis = -1
if (fs.FileExists(filename))
{
    var file = fs.GetFile(filename);
    millis = Date.parse(file.DateLastModified) / 1000;
}
WSH.Echo(millis);
```

The `/* */` will comment out the batch script while running as a JScript, and the `@if (@a==@b) @end` and `goto :eof` will skip the JScript while running as a batch script

```
>epoch.bat epoch.bat
Last modified (epoch-seconds): 1533282229

>epoch.bat "epoch.bat"
Last modified (epoch-seconds): 1533282229

>epoch.bat notareal.file
Last modified (epoch-seconds): -1
```